# PHP - Finish HTML tags that haven't been closed?

Tags: php, html, string, formatting

Let's say that I get an input of something like:

```
<strong>bunch <em>of</em> <span>random text
```

I want code to be able to take this string and turn it into:

```
<strong>bunch <em>of</em> <span>random text</span></strong>
```

Comment: Look at Tidy: http://php.net/tidy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the first place to look is the [Tidy extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.cleanrepair.php)

```
$html = "<strong>bunch <em>of</em> <span>random text";
$tidy = tidy_parse_string($html, array('clean' => true, 'show-body-only' => true));
$tidy->cleanRepair();
echo $tidy;
```